# Is Triple Booting Possible?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Is it possible for one to triple boot three linux distros or (2 distros together with windows)?

Comment: I have a *testing* box here with 7 OSes installed over the 3 installed drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I did many times. Windows + Ubuntu 18.04 + Ubuntu 16.04